# Android drawables are not recognized by AndroidStudio if I use dpi subfolders

Tags: android, android-studio

I have just started the [Treehouse](http://www.teamtreehouse.com) Android development course, I have also asked this question on their forums without any luck.

**DATA**

- AndroidStudio v 1.2.2, the course is based on v0.86 I think
- OS / DE: Manjaro Linux, KDE

I have copied the image files inside the drawable folder, each into their specific dpi folder.

I have created the ImageView for a mail_title.png, and added the src as the full path to the png. When I do that, the image loads into the preview screen, and I can work with it, but If I try to build the app it just says the value of src cannot be a string.

So then I tried to point to it as a resource. On many forums and the android documentation I only found that I should reference it through a "pointer" @drawable/main_title , when I downloaded the projectfiles from the course I saw thats how they did it too.

If I try to rebuild now it gives the following error:

```
Error:(14, 22) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/main_title').
```

Then I tried to create a resource inside strings.xml, I found some autocomplete function that pointed me in "the right direction", of course it did not work!, same error as before. I have tried using absolute paths as well without luck.

Right now It shows R as "cannot resolve symbol R" in the MAinActivity file. I figured out by reading online that this is due to my drawable not existing problem.

Then I created a refs.xml in values and added

main_title.png
I actually tried with and without the extension (png)

After that I clicked on the IDE suggestion to create a drawable folder and it just created a @drawable folder inside of layout....

Basically it says it cannot resolve directory @drawable from activity_main.xml

and also

```
Error:(3, 33) String types not allowed (at 'main_title' with value 'main_title.png'). on the refs.xml file (this happens whether I use the extension (png) or not.
```

The only solution I have found is to just copy one version fo the images to the main drawables folder, and deleting all of the subfolders, if I don't delte them then it also doesn't work...

So, as you can see I'm kinda lost... Any help would be appreciated. I'm a python backend developer and I'm pretty comfortable usiong Pycharm (IntelliJ for python), but somehow I feel Android Studio has me totally lost!

Comment: and your sure your files are under `res/drawable-hdpi/` (and similar) folders? The `res` folder should be at the same level as the `java` folder that contains source code.

Comment: Yes, the full path is:` /home/username/AndroidStudioProjects/athelas-adventures/app/src/main/res/drawable/ ` and the java folders is at `/home/username/AndroidStudioProjects/athelas-adventures/app/src/main/java`

Comment: My sub folders were: `drawable-{hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi}` // 4 folders just using sh notation

Comment: This comment does not make sense to me "@drawable folder inside of layout....". Make sure that there are no-sub folders under `res/layout` or `res/drawable-...` folders. There might be a different error causing the R file not to build, thus you not being able to link to your drawables.

Comment: That was something I tried following AndroidStudio suggestions. I have already deleted that folder, it seemed it was a standard IntelliJ suggestion for unknown references. Inside layout there are no folders, and inside drawable there are only he 4 dpi folders I mentioned before. The only way AndroidStudio will recognize the drawable elements is by copying them to the drawable root. (Thanks for your help Chris)

Comment: So just to make sure, `res` folder should probably have the following sub folders: `layout`, `values`, `drawable`, `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-xdpi`, and `drawable-xxdpi`. There should be no sub-folders in any of those folders, they all belong under `res`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, in case anyone wonders, I solved it following both Cris and Rob advices. I installed appcompat v7 and put my img resources (png,jpd, etc) directly inside my drawable folder. Then I created a folder for each dpi resolution inside the **res** folder, NOT inside the drawable folder.

Answer (score 1):

I use eclipse but i think its pretty much the same, you should have you various drawable folders, then you have to include the R (res folder)

```
import com.example.project.R;
```

and then call them by reference

```
R.drawables.main_title
```

Note you dont need to specify which drawable folder , adroid does that for you.

Also if you are getting unresolved errors with R then you may need to have the appcompatv7 library inlcuded in your project.

Comment: Thanks Rob, even so it doens't recognize R if I set the subfolders, it's like the system just doesn't automatically parse them

Comment: Might there be soethng in the manifest I have to add for it to parse different resolutions?

Comment: Do you have R.java in your Gen folder? if not then its more than likely you are not adding the appcompatv7 library to your project. once downloaded and added as a libraryto your project, then do a clean build and the R errors should disappear and you can refrence your drawables. Android parses the different size for you or picks from the most suitable so nothing is needed in your manifest

Comment: You do not need a drawable folder with the sub folders, each of the diffrent sized folders are directly in the res folder

Comment: Just did that, it does recognize the @drawabele element, but it Failed ro convert the items into drawables... So they weren't rendered

Comment: Should I copy some version of the images into the basic drawable directory as well? this is the current state of the [folder](http://imgur.com/qywNxvt)

Comment: They look fine. each folder should now have a version of the correct size in. Note however your image should only need to be in one of them for it to be picked for any device. these folders are meant for release time so that all the images look correct on all devices. by placing your images in just the drawable folder for now means it should be picked and rendered. WHat errors are you getting now?

Comment: If i don't put any images inside the drawable folder and just in the dpi onesit doesn't work, it says Failed to convert <route to drawable> into drawable.  if I put some images in the drawable then it works just fine.

Comment: i think i have always started with all my images in the drawable and when i come to release i then create all the others and put them in the correct ones, i am sure in eclipse it doesnt matter what fodler they are in as long as its in one. Anyway i hoep this has helped you :-)

Comment: It has thank you! I will make a complete answer when I get back to my PC. thanks rob